# How to exec vscode in wsl terminal

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I add `export PATH=$PATH:'/mnt/d/install/work/Microsoft VS Code/bin'`  to zshrc of wsl . But when running command `code .` , I get `<3>init: (13215) ERROR: UtilAcceptVsock:244: accept4 failed 110`. Are there anything I miss?  What I installed:

1. vscode (wins)
2. wsl ubuntu 22.04 lts
3. oh-my-zsh power10k

Comment: Does [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1602624) help you ?

Comment: Still doesn't work

Comment: Please be clearer. Do you get the same errors as before ?

Comment: Do you get the same error if you run `notepad.exe` in WSL?

Comment: Also, from the error, I'm assuming you are on Windows 11 - Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

You are likely seeing [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/7947) where some long environment variable is causing the WSL/Windows interop to break down.

A couple of notes from the issue:

- If you can identify which environment variable (probably being set in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`) is the culprit, you can probably just it that way.
- The error message itself seems to be unique to Windows 11, at least according to the person who submitted the issue.  On Windows 10, no error appears, but the Windows process never launches.  So I'm assuming (and hoping) that you are on Windows 11.
- The bug is fixed in the latest release, which is in Preview at the moment.  If you *are* on Windows 11, you can install it via the Microsoft Store.  It's labeled *"Windows Subsystem for Linux Preview"*.

  While there are a number of issues that have been fixed (and other improvements) in the Preview, there is at least one substantial issue where WSL cannot be started through Windows SSH.  That shouldn't be a showstopper for most people.